# want amazon prime video on android tablet

Tags: sync

I HAVE a Toshiba wt10-a tablet and want to access my amazon prime video account to download and watch movies.   I am not a techie, .  All other devices are iPhones and kindles and want the Toshiba to connect to them if possible.  Thank you!

Comment: Umm, try to download [Amazon Underground](https://www.amazon.com/underground) and then install [Amazon Video](http://www.amazon.com/Amazon-com-Amazon-Video/dp/B00N28818A) app?

Answer (score 0):

To get Amazon video on a "regular" Android tablet, you need to install the Amazon App Store, then install Amazon Video. [This](http://www.amazon.com/gp/video/splash/sd/t/appstore)  should walk you through the process and is Amazon's official way of supporting Amazon Video on non-Kindle Android tablets.